# Отключение JS и CSS на отдельных страницах WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет.
На сайте есть куча плагинов, которые нужны только на определенных страницах (или типах записей) но подключают свои стили и скрипты глобально, от чего он тормозит...
Можно ли, к примеру, в functins.php вписать какой-то код, который будет блокировать подключение локальных и внешних CSS/JS ?

Вроде такого:

```
if ( page_id=(123, 3844, 4857) > remove_this  
     {
        /wp_content/plugins/someplugin/someJS.js;
        /wp_content/plugins/someplugin/css.css;
        https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/jquery-ui.min.js;
     } 
    
    elseif  page_id=(475, 675) > remove_this  
        /wp_content/plugins/someplugin/other.css;
        https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/noneed.min.js;
    }
    
    elseif  post_type is (costum, onemore) > remove_this  
        /wp_content/plugins/someplugin/deletme.css;
        https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/jquery-ui.min.js;
    }
```

*на код внимания не обращайте, я в этом "ноль", он просто для демонстрации логики)*

Comment: Проще использовать плагин Plugin Organizer: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/

Comment: А так да - можно, я писал такой код

Comment: KAGG Design, дайте, пожалуйста, прямую ссылку на ваш код (в профиле не смог найти, к сожалению)

Comment: Вам Valerii Vasiliev ниже дал правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дя этого есть специальные функции [wp_dequeue_style()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_dequeue_style), [wp_dequeue_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_dequeue_script)

фрагмент кода для отключения ненужных стилей-скриптов вставить в functions.php

```
 add_action(
            'wp_enqueue_scripts',
             function() {
                 if (is_page(123) || is_page(3844) || is_page(4857)) {
                    
                    // Отключаем стили
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name2' );
                    
                    // Отключаем скрипты
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name2' );
                    
                 } elseif (is_page(475) || is_page(675)) {
                    
                    // Отключаем стили
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name2' );
                    
                    // Отключаем скрипты
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name2' );
                    
                 } elseif (is_singular( array( 'costum', 'onemore' )) {
                    
                    // Отключаем стили
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_style( 'style-name2' );
                    
                    // Отключаем скрипты
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name' );
                    
                    wp_dequeue_script( 'script-name2' );
                 }
            },
            99
       );
```

В качестве 'style-name', 'style-name2', 'script-name', 'script-name2' указывать названия стилей-скриптов, которые используются при их подключение.

Названия скриптов и стилей хранятся в переменных $wp_scripts, $wp_styles

Добавьте в теме где-нибудь следующий фрагмент для получения названий

```
$result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // Print all loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
       $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    // Print all loaded Styles (CSS)
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
       $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . ";";
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Названия handles стилей и скриптов можно посмотреть прямо в html-коде страницы. Для css код выгляит так: `<link rel='stylesheet' id='medusa-css' href='https://site.com/wp-content/themes/medusa/style.css?ver=1.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />` В id есть текст `medusa`, который и является handle стиля. Для js скриптов - аналогично.

Comment: И приведённый код для получения стилей и скриптов будет работать только на хуке, например, `wp_print_scripts`, `wp_print_styles`, `wp_print_footer_scripts`

Comment: Спасибо, но осталось еще как-то внешние заблокировать (_https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/noneed.min.js;)

Comment: @Garik а как этот скрипт подключается?

Comment: Например, один из плагинов добавляет в head <script   type='text/javascript' src='_https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

Comment: @Garik а для людей без телепатических способностей?

Comment: Для них - не знаю, сорри. Я ньюб 80 уровня, мало что понимаю в этом )

Comment: @Garik а я вам сразу сказал, что для вас лучше всего - использовать плагин Plugin Organizer. Он полностью блокирует запуск указанных плагинов на странице, и вам не надо думать о том, как блокировать запускаемые им внешние скрипты.